# Docker how to deploy dotnet nginx ? (without .csproj)

Tags: c#, .net, docker, kubernetes, yaml

Hello I want to deploy in docker: .net, kestrel and nginx.
I have a project assembly without .csproj (it is possible or need .csproj ?)
But when I try to deploy my .net project in Docker I had status Exitet.

---

```
Dockerfile 

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["bash"]

CMD ["build1", "WebApplication4.dll"]
```

---

My project files

```
appsettings.Development.json

appsettings.json

Dockerfile

WebApplication4

WebApplication4.deps.json

WebApplication4.dll

WebApplication4.pdb

WebApplication4.runtimeconfig.json

WebApplication4.Views.dll

WebApplication4.Views.pdb

web.config

wwwroot
```

---

`docker ps --all` output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS               NAMES

0f1880a89999        build1              "bash build1 WebAppl…"   4 seconds ago       Exited (127) 3 seconds ago                       sleepy_bardeen
```

---

If you have a interes how to resolve. Answer.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS final

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication4.dll"]
```

Right now. I try to find decision how to add nginx and kestrel ?

Comment: you suppose to build it in docker container not just to copy...

Comment: Can you please share the container logs? (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) Also, the entry point is "BASH", are you trying to use this container as builder? If so, your build process is not correct (https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

Comment: Sorry I didn't write. But I am recently started to study docker and how to deploy and I don't know how will be right. But i want  just  to deploy .net assembly in docker. No I don't want to build process because it is ready assembly.

Comment: Sorry but when I try to run container without ENTRYPOINT ["bash"]      I had error                                       Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"build1\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown                                                                                                                     docker logs

Comment: Hello thx for your help. I resolve my problem.                                                                                                                             Right now. I try to find decision how to add nginx and kestrel ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks. Right now try to add nginx and have problem with nginx Welcom default page.

nginx Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx 
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  dotnet:
    build: ./build2
    expose:
    - "80"

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: ngix-dotnet
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft suggests to use NGINX as a reverse proxy to .NET Core applications. You need to build the image and install NGINX in your dockerfile.

For example:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS final

# Nginx
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y --no-install-recommends nginx && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    apt clean && \
    rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY MyProject/docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:4000
EXPOSE 4000 80
```

As you can see I'm installing NGINX in my dockerfile and exposing `4000` and `80` port numbers. In the `nginx.conf` file NGINX listens for port `80` and pass requests to `4000` which is the port my .NET Core application listens.

You can find further information in this article: https://piotrgankiewicz.com/2017/06/12/asp-net-core-deployment-using-docker-nginx-and-ubuntu-server/

Comment: Thanks. Right now try to add nginx and have problem with nginx Welcom default page.                                  nginx

Dockerfile

FROM nginx

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

COPY default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/



docker-compose.yaml


version: '3'
services:
  dotnet:
    build: ./build2
    expose:
    - "80"

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: ngix-dotnet
    ports:
      - "80:80"